# Linking C to JNI, independent of JDK version

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am calling a Java application inside my C program, via JNI.

Having installed JDK 1.8, I have the following JNI `.so` libraries on my system:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
```

To make these two files known to `ldconfig`, I can create links to them in `/usr/lib64/`, or create a `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/java.conf` file which lists them.

This allows me to compile my C code as follows:

```
gcc -I$JAVA_HOME/include/ -I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux/ \
-L/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/amd64/jli \
-L/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/amd64/server/ \
callSomeJava.c -ljvm -ljli
```

This feels like a system hack rather than a reliable way to develop and deploy JNI code. The JDK does not feel like it has exposed these libs to the OS in a way that encourages reliance upon them.

My questions are as follows:

- Why does the JDK contain a `linker name` (*lib.so*) rather than `real name` (*lib.so.N.N*) of these libs? [3.1.1. Shared Library Names](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)
- Where *should* I get the required libs from, so they are already installed in a linkable manner without my system hacks?
- How can I compile/deploy my C, in a way which:

  - is not dependent on me manually maintaining `ldconfig` whenever I update my JDK?
  - allows the resulting `a.out` to find the libs in deployment environments which have not had my `ldconfig` hacks?

Comment: I found getting the JVM lib dynamically from env variables, `java` executable symlink information and /or Debian alternative system and then using `dlopen`/`dlsym` to get at the functions more versatile than linking with `-l`

Comment: That sounds great, and ties in with a suggestion here https://web.archive.org/web/20120626011516/http://java.sun.com:80/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html#24891.